# How Can I Get Exception in my try catch in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm making a program and I want an exception, so the program wont crash.
If the user puts a string that is not in the `else if statements` then it would not crash.

Also, I tried doing that for the `integer`, so if someone tries to write something that is not an `integer` it wont crash. And the program will catch it and would say that it isn't an `integer`.

How can I get exception in my `try catch` in `java`.

Thank for your help

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; 


public class WeightOnADifferentPlanet { 
public static void main ( String[] args ){   
 Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ); 


System.out.println("Where do you want to travel:?");
try{
     String planetName = scan.nextLine(); 
 }
 catch(/*need help here*/){
     System.out.println("Please check your spelling");
 }



 System.out.println("Please enter your weight:"); 
 try{
     int weight = scan.nextInt(); 
 }
 catch(InputMismatchException e)
 {
    System.out.println("That is not an integer"); 
 }
 double earthCalculation = weight * 1.0; 
 double jupiterCalculation = weight * (21.0 / 8.0); //check
 double marsCalculation = weight * (3.0 / 8.0); 
 double mercuryCalculation = weight * (3.0 / 10.0); 
 double neptuneCalculation = weight * (11.0 / 10.0); //check 
 double plutoCalculation = weight * (7.0 / 10.0); 
 double saturnCalculation = weight * (6.0 / 5.0); //check
 double uranusCalculation = weight * (9.0 / 10.0); 
 double venusCalculation = weight * (7.0 / 8.0);


 if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Earth")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+earthCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Jupiter"))
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+jupiterCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mars")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+marsCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mercury")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+mercuryCalculation+" pounds."); 
 } 
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Neptune")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+neptuneCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Pluto")) 
 {
    System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+plutoCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Saturn")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+saturnCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
  else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Uranus")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+uranusCalculation+" pounds."); 
 } 
   else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Venus")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+venusCalculation+" pounds."); 

 }


     }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing it and here is the result. 
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class WeightOnADifferentPlanet { 
static Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ); 

public static void main ( String[] args ){   



System.out.println("What planet do you want to travela:?");

     String planetName = scan.nextLine(); 



 System.out.println("Please enter your weight:"); 
 int weight = Integer();


 //int weight = scan.nextInt();


 double earthCalculation = weight * 1.0; 
 double jupiterCalculation = weight * (21.0 / 8.0); //check
 double marsCalculation = weight * (3.0 / 8.0); 
 double mercuryCalculation = weight * (3.0 / 10.0); 
 double neptuneCalculation = weight * (11.0 / 10.0); //check 
 double plutoCalculation = weight * (7.0 / 10.0); 
 double saturnCalculation = weight * (6.0 / 5.0); //check
 double uranusCalculation = weight * (9.0 / 10.0); 
 double venusCalculation = weight * (7.0 / 8.0);


 if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Earth")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+earthCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Jupiter"))
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+jupiterCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mars")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+marsCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mercury")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+mercuryCalculation+" pounds."); 
 } 
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Neptune")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+neptuneCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Pluto")) 
 {
    System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+plutoCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
 else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Saturn")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+saturnCalculation+" pounds."); 
 }
  else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Uranus")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+uranusCalculation+" pounds."); 
 } 
   else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Venus")) 
 {
   System.out.println("Your weight on "+planetName+" is: "+venusCalculation+" pounds."); 

 }
   else {
       System.out.println("Planet not recognized");
   }
 }



 public static int Integer(){
      while (true)
      {
       try
       {
        return scan.nextInt();
       }
       catch (InputMismatchException e)
       {
           scan.next();
           System.out.print("That’s not an integer. Try again: ");
       }

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `scan.nextInt();` will only scan an integer anyways, so there shouldn't be any need to catch non integers

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your program:

- `String planetName` needs to be declared outside of the try block.
- You shouldn't have `planetName = scan.nextLine();` in a try/catch. You should figure out a way to keep asking the user for a planet name until they get a proper one.
- Also, the `int weight` needs to be declared outside of the try block.
- Same thing here, you need to figure out a way to keep asking the user for an integer if they don't give you one (e.g. you get an exception).

**EDIT**: As suggested by MasterBlaster, you should also close out your scanner with `scan.close()`

Comment: Don't forget [`scan.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) at the end to prevent a resource leak.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use exceptions. You can enter anything for planet and it won't crash, since you are checking for `nextLine()`. For weight, just check if `scan.hasNextInt()` before setting the weight.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 


public class WeightOnADifferentPlanet { 
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("Where do you want to travel? ");
        String planetName = scan.nextLine(); 

        System.out.print("Please enter your weight: ");
        int weight = 0;
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            weight = scan.nextInt();

            double earthCalculation = weight * 1.0; 
            double jupiterCalculation = weight * (21.0 / 8.0); //check
            double marsCalculation = weight * (3.0 / 8.0); 
            double mercuryCalculation = weight * (3.0 / 10.0); 
            double neptuneCalculation = weight * (11.0 / 10.0); //check 
            double plutoCalculation = weight * (7.0 / 10.0); 
            double saturnCalculation = weight * (6.0 / 5.0); //check
            double uranusCalculation = weight * (9.0 / 10.0); 
            double venusCalculation = weight * (7.0 / 8.0);

            if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Earth")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + earthCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Jupiter")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + jupiterCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mars")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + marsCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mercury")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + mercuryCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Neptune")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + neptuneCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Pluto")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + plutoCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Saturn")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + saturnCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Uranus")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + uranusCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else if (planetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Venus")) {
                System.out.println("Your weight on " + planetName + " is: " + venusCalculation + " pounds."); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Planet not recognized");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid weight");
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that helped a lot. But for the integer i need the program to give an error message rather it just stopping. So i ended up putting an exception in a try catch in a new method and returned it to the program